# i need a solution to do type parameter overloading

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, generics, overloading

I need type parameter overloading as such:

`Public Class Map(Of TKey, TValue)`

`Public Class Map(Of TKey As IEquatable(Of TKey), TValue)`

so that i can `New Map(Of Human)` and the compiler will automatically match it to `Public Class Map(Of TKey, TValue)` and if i `new Map(Of String)` the compiler will automatically match it to `Public Class Map(Of TKey As IEquatable(Of TKey), TValue)` (since String is an IEquatable(Of String))

Right now my solution is to give the class different names as such:

`Public Class Map(Of TKey, TValue)`

`Public Class EqMap(Of TKey As IEquatable(Of TKey), TValue)`

But I'm looking for a better solution

Comment: @Jodrell the compiler definitely could choose. when you do parameter overloading f(object) and f(string) Isn't any string also an object? The principle is the same here, take the one that fits best

Comment: I'm personally thinking that the solution you have is the sensible one. If the two classes are different in behavious having the same name sounds like it will cause confusion. I'd have two different named classes and you can always have a factory or something examine your types to return the most appropriate class. Sprinkle on some inheritance or interfaces to make sure that they can all be treated the same and you're sorted.

Comment: @Pacerir, doh, these are classes, .Net does not support class overloading as far as I am aware. What you want is inheritance and (contra/co)variance. The classes will have to have differnt names as Chris states.

Comment: @Chris exactly. my problem now is that the 2 classes have similar behaviors

Comment: @Jodrell don't delete ur comments!

Comment: @Pacerier: that's not a problem, that's just a need to use inheritance properly and possibly refactor your code so that you have as much common stuff in methods that don't change and the things that matter if its equatable or not can then override whatever they need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I don't speak VB... but in c# (which you have in your tags) what you want is

```
Map<TKey,TValue>
{
    // implementation
}
```

and

```
Map<Tkey,TValue>
   where TKey: IEquatable
{

}
```

unfortunately this isn't supported because constraints are not part of the signature you will have to provide different signatures and using different names (or possibly namespaces) is the cleanest solution IMO.

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution, better than what you propose. Personally I would prefer `EquatableMap` to `EqMap`, `EquatableMap` could inherit `Map` if the `is` relationship and reuse was beneficial.

.Net does not support class overloading, who knows, maybe in .Net 5.0. It would be useful.